# jQuery replace url in quotes with a string variable

Tags: jquery, xml, ajax

Can I use a string and substitute it for the quotes where the arrow is pointing below?

```
$(document).ready(function(){      
   $.ajax({         
   type: "GET",  
   url: "http://mydomain/test.xml",      <---- Right here can I use a variable like str
   dataType: "xml",          
   success: 
   function(xml){  
     etc...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   var someUrl = "http://mydomain/test.xml";

   $.ajax({         
   type: "GET",  
   url: someUrl,
   dataType: "xml",          
   success: 
   function(xml){  
     etc...
```

Comment: I might've been faster (slightly), but, since it's essentially the *same* answer, have a +1, sir! =)

Comment: Yes that what I needed to know.  Just wanted to make sure I wasn't going down the wrong path.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var ajaxUrl = "http://mydomain/test.xml";

   $.ajax({         
   type: "GET",  
   url: ajaxUrl,      <---- Right here can I use a variable like str
   dataType: "xml",          
   success: 
   function(xml){  
     etc...
```

Comment: Also is the context still in my select tag or can i just add like my select to it like $("select[name='selectName']") as my context:?

Comment: @Marc, I haven't changed your context, or much else, at all, the only thing I changed is assigning the URL to a variable before the `$.ajax()` call. So assuming it worked before, it should still work now as-is.